# Box2D up view physics on LibGDX

Tags: box2d, libgdx, physics

Hy, i´m doing a game with a flat platform looked from upside, and i has circles on it that i can move.

Here an example:

[image: example]

I dont know how to make a Box2D object so it apply friction force to objects on it, theres not so much code about it, most examples was a rear view which objects are on top and has bottom gravity.

Most examples i´ve found:

```
    world=new World(new Vector2(0, -100), true);
```

My case:

```
    world=new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
```

I hope u can understand me.

EDIT: I think this fit my needs

[FrictionJointl](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/FrictionJoint.html)

But i cant understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Body.setLinearDamping()` and `Body.setAngularDamping()` on your circles. That will automatically apply friction to them. Alternatively you may do this yourself by using `Body.applyLinearImpulse()` and `Body.applyAngularImpulse()` in the opposite direction of your velocity/rotation.